# Why is Webpack 4 runtimeChunk in all entrypoints?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am currently upgrading WP from v1.2 => v4.1 on a large commercial application. I am having an issue where splitChunks is creating multiple instances of my store for each entry point (The store we are using is extremely old and outdated, but that is out of my control ATM).

The issue as I see it is that runtime code is being added to each entry point which executes the same module multiple times - I succeeded in recreating the issue in a sandboxed environment and when I added a single runtimeChunk to my config this extracted the runtime code into a single file and resolved my issue - however when I applied this to my application - a runtime file WAS created, but runtimeChunk remained in each entrypoint also and so the problem still persists. Below is an example of my current config.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
  app: [
    'babel-polyfill', 
    'whatwg-fetch', 
    './src/app/app' 
  ],
  testEntry: './src/modules/testEntry.js',
},
output: {
  pathinfo: true,
  publicPath: '/',
  chunkFilename: '[id].js'
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
  ]
},
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      commons: {
        name: 'commons',
        filename: "js/[name].js",
        test: /\.js(x)?$/,
        chunks: "initial",
        minChunks: 1
      }
    }
  },
  runtimeChunk: {
    name: 'shared',
  },
},
mode: 'development', 
devtool: 'eval', 
devServer: {
  contentBase: __dirname, 
  port: 5000
},
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html'
  })
]
```

};

Is another way I can force runtime code to be executed only once?

EDITED UPDATE

I have now updated to webpack 4.17 (latest) and now oddly - when I use the single runtime option - my entry bundles are not generated

Comment: why are using runTimeChunk : shared  ?

Comment: @Sakhi Mansoor. Well... I'm possibly mistaken but I want the runtime code to run only once for multiple entrypoints (thereby executing my store module once). In the sandbox environment I created this IS the result I see. But doesn't seem to transfer to the real application scenario for somme reason.